# How to get custom section index titles as in Contacts app in iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

i just want to create custom concat list with index section (index list must be same as default contact list).
For example if i create any contact without name then came with # index also if any contact start with numeric number then it also came with #index.I am using below code but no luck.

```
func retrieveContactsWithStore(store: CNContactStore){

   let keysToFetch = 
   [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), 
   CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactImageDataKey, 
   CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [Any]
   let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! 
   [CNKeyDescriptor])
   request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault
   var cnContacts = [CNContact]()
   do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: request){
            (contact, cursor) -> Void in
            if (!contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty) {
            }
            if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactImageDataKey) {
                if let contactImageData = contact.imageData {
                    print(UIImage(data: contactImageData) ??  "") 
                }
            } else {
                // No Image available
            }
            if (!contact.emailAddresses.isEmpty) {
            }
            cnContacts.append(contact)
            self.contacts = cnContacts
        }
    } catch let error {
        NSLog("Fetch contact error: \(error)")
    }

    NSLog(">>>> Contact list:")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         for contact in self.contacts {
            let fullName = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName) ?? "No Name"
            let contactKey = String(fullName.prefix(1))
            if var contactValues = self.contactsDictionary[contactKey] {
                contactValues.append(contact)
                self.contactsDictionary[contactKey] = contactValues
            } else {
                self.contactsDictionary[contactKey] = [contact]
            }
        }

        // 2
        self.contactsSectionTitles = [String](self.contactsDictionary.keys)
        self.contactsSectionTitles = self.contactsSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })            
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // 1
    return contactsSectionTitles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection 
section: Int) -> String? {
    return contactsSectionTitles[section]
}
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return contactsSectionTitles
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if your ViewController is assigned the DataSource and Delegate for the tableview?
In Code:
`tableView.dataSource = self`
`tableView.delegate = self`
For storyboard, google search for a video if you don't know

Comment: Getting problem in sort index order not in table reload, I want section index like default contact list.

Comment: That index is a native swift api, so you are in luck. Check out this tutorial:
https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/

Comment: Whats up app does same, can we achieve like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution,
i followed this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalizedindexedcollation

```swift
class ObjectTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation()
    var sections: [[AnyObject]] = []
    var objects: [AnyObject] = [] {
        didSet {
            let selector: Selector = "localizedTitle"
            sections = Array(count: collation.sectionTitles.count, repeatedValue: [])

            let sortedObjects = collation.sortedArrayFromArray(objects, collationStringSelector: selector)
            for object in sortedObjects {
                let sectionNumber = collation.sectionForObject(object, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sections[sectionNumber].append(object)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDelegate

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {
        return collation.sectionTitles[section]
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String] {
        return collation.sectionIndexTitles
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
        return collation.sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current().sectionTitles[section]
}

func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
   
    return  UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current().sectionTitles
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    return UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current().section(forSectionIndexTitle: index)
}
```